# How do I return a ADODB.Connection from a function in VBA?

Tags: sql-server, ms-access, database-connection, vba, adodb

I have a large Access VBA/SQL Server application. In each function there is the same ADODB connection.

How do I replace those with a single function that can be called each time, to save space.

```vb
Public Function ConnectionString() As ADODB.Connection
    Dim CN As ADODB.Connection
    
    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection
        
    With CN
        .Provider = "Microsoft.Access.OLEDB.10.0"
        .Properties("Data Provider").Value = "SQLOLEDB"
        .Properties("Data Source").Value = DLookup("Source", "tbl_Connection")
        .Properties("Initial Catalog").Value = DLookup("Catalog", "tbl_Connection")
        .Properties("Integrated Security").Value = SSPI
        .Open
    End With
        
    ConnectionString = CN
    
End Function
```

It seems like this should return that connection, but there is an error message:

> User-Defined Function not found

on the line `ConnectionString = CN`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to `Set` the return value:

```
Set ConnectionString = CN
```

---

Plus, if it's always the same ADODB connection anyway, you can save it in a variable and "recycle" it from there, so the actual creation of the connection happens exactly once (when the `ConnectionString` function  is called for the first time).

```
Private CN As ADODB.Connection 'variable in the module - NOT in the function

Public Function ConnectionString() As ADODB.Connection

If CN Is Nothing Then

    Set CN = New ADODB.Connection

    With CN
        'do stuff
    End With

End If

Set ConnectionString = CN

End Function
```

Comment: That worked! Such a simple solution. Should have tried that, but I'm still pretty new at this.

Answer (score 0):

```
From sub caller:
    Dim DBConnection As New ADODB.Connection
    Call getDBConnection(ServerInfo, DBConnection)
The sub called:

Public Sub getDBConnection(ByRef paramServerInfo As ConnState, ByRef pCN As ADODB.Connection)
    Dim flagConnect As Boolean
    Dim errConnect As String
    Dim optionConn As String
    Dim strConn As String
    
    optionConn = "16427"
    strConn = "Provider=MSDASQL.1;Persist Security Info=False;Extended Properties=""" & _
            "DRIVER={" & paramServerInfo.ODBC & "};" & _
            "DATABASE=" & paramServerInfo.Database & ";" & _
            "SERVER=" & paramServerInfo.Server & ";" & _
            "USER=" & paramServerInfo.UserName & ";" & _
            "PASSWORD=" & paramServerInfo.Password & ";" & _
            "Port=" & paramServerInfo.Port & ";" & _
            "OPTION=" & optionConn & ";"
    
    On Error Resume Next
    paramServerInfo.Conneted = False
    Do
        pCN.CursorLocation = adUseClient
        pCN.Open strConn
        paramServerInfo.Conneted = Not pCN Is Nothing
        paramServerInfo.LastMsg = Err.Description
        If Not paramServerInfo.Conneted Then
            If MsgBox("Existe un problema al intentar conectar con la Base de Datos" & vbCrLf & paramServerInfo.LastMsg & vbCrLf & "Por favor determine que hacer:", vbCritical + vbAbortRetryIgnore) = vbAbort Then
                Exit Sub
            End If
        End If
    Loop Until paramServerInfo.Conneted
End Sub
```